# jquery realtime variable (for responsive)

Tags: jquery

This code give me document width when document ready.

```
jQuery().ready(function(e) {
   var sayfaboyut = jQuery(document).width();
   document.write(sayfaboyut);
});
```

But I want real time variable. When I change document width I want to get that width real time.

How can I do that ?

Comment: The variable *is* always real time. What you are looking for is a way to *query* the variable continuously :) https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: ... or listen window resize event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to `resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
     console.log($(window).width())
}).resize();
```

Comment: its working only if i resize the window but I must get loaded window size to.

Comment: @sinanisler Just trigger the resize event, I have updated the code.

Comment: look http://www.sinanisler.com/demo/responsive/ open window smaller then 990px and refresh its not giving variable how we fix that ?

Comment: @sinanisler You haven't used `console.log` in your code, if you want to create a responsive page, why don't you use CSS3 Media Queries?

Comment: @sinanisler IE8 and below do not support it, if you want to make it work in older browsers you can use this plugin http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has a built-in method for this:

```
$(window).resize(function () { 
    var sayfaboyut = jQuery(document).width();
   document.write(sayfaboyut);
});
```

The resize function will be called whenever the window changes size. Note, this will be height and width resizing.

Another answer I found suggested that you should not react to every call to resize, as it may make the browser unresponsive. Instead they suggested re-queing a timer as follows:

```
function doSomething() {
    alert("I'm done resizing for the moment");
};

var resizeTimer;
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(doSomething, 100);
});
```

Comment: its working only if i resize the window but I must get loaded window size to.

Comment: You can get the loaded window size in the normal way you showed in your post.